# Debug.Fail gives me a "Dispatcher processing has been suspended" error

Tags: .net, wpf, dispatcher

I had a problem in code that caused a Debug.Fail to be called. I use Debug.Assert and Debug.Fail quite a lot, since it not only gives me instant notification that a problem exists, but also information about what and where the problem is located.

But this time the Debug.Fail itself caused an even bigger problem, since the UI (WPF) froze becuse of the following error:

> Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed.

**Is there anything I can do to make Debug.Fail succeed?** I most definitely do not want to have code around by Debug.Fail to check whether to Invoke or BeginInvoke.

**EDIT:** I suppose replacing the DefaultTraceListener would do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Debug.Fail` will by default use the `DefaultTraceListener`. Using ILSpy, I could see that `DefaultTraceListener.Fail` makes a call to `AssertWrapper.ShowAssert`. To get around the problem, replace the `DefaultTraceListener` with your own that has Dispatcher guards around the call to `AssertWrapper.ShowAssert`.

Voila! Now you can call `Debug.Assert` and `Debug.Fail` without bothering about dispatcher issues.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're Debug.Fail from DependencyProperty change callback.

Full answer you could find here: ['Dispatcher processing has been suspended' InvalidOperationException when calling ShowDialog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/44962927-006e-4629-9aa3-100357861442)

Comment: I saw that one too when I googled it and it's quite possible there's a property changed callback way down the callstack. But why do I have to care about that when Debug.Failing? I really don't want to be bothered with threading issues for that.